# Sweet alert in ajax and php content not working

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to get a value from my database and then run an update using sweet alert pop-up but it is not working. The alert seem to pop-up and once the value is entered, it displays the value entered but not working. below is my actual ajax code:

**viewproduct.php**

```
<script>
     
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btnupdatestock').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        //var new_stock = $(this).val();


        swal("Add Stock:", {
          content: "input",
            
        })
        .then((updateStock) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'stock-in.php',
            data:{
                stock_up: updateStock,
            },
            success: function(data){
                 swal(`Updated: ${updateStock}`);
            },
            error: function(data){
                swal(`Error updating: ${updateStock}`);
            }
        });
            
            
          
        });
    
        });
    });


</script>
```

the above method was designed to trigger sql in **stock-in.php** and the code in **stock-in.php** is below:

```
<?php

include_once'connectdb.php';

if($_SESSION['useremail']=="" OR $_SESSION['role']=="Admin"){
    
    
    header('location:index.php');
}



$idd=$_GET['id'];  
    $select=$pdo->prepare("select * from tbl_product where pid=$idd");          
    $select->execute();
        while($row=$select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            $productName    = $row['pname'];
            $oldstock       = $row['pstock'];
            
            

            //$id=$_POST['uid'];
            $stockup=$_POST['stock_up'];
            alert('I clicked');
            
            $new_stock = $oldstock + $stockup;

                $sql="UPDATE `tbl_product` SET `pstock` = ? WHERE  pid= ? ";
                    $update=$pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $update->execute([$new_stock, $idd]);

            if($result){
               echo'Stock updated!';
            }else{
              echo'Error in updating stock';  
            }
        }

?>
```

below is a picture of my UI that shows pop-up but it's not updating.
[image]

This is what I intend to do: If a user clicks on update and enters a value say 50, it should retrieve the old stock (database, say 100) and add to the new stock (value entered, say 50) and then update the database with 150. I am stuck here and any help would be appreciated. **Thanks.**

Comment: What is a call to `alert` doing in the middle of PHP code? Also, if you are doing `fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`, shouldn't it then be `$row->pname` instead of `$row['pname']`?

Comment: Hi you didn't pass `id` value to backend page .

Comment: I did but that wasn't the issue. thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btnupdatestock').click(function() {

            swal("Add Stock:", {
                buttons: true,
                closeModal: true,
                content: "input",
            }).then((updateStock) => {
                if (updateStock === "") {
                    swal("You need to write something!");
                return false
            }else{
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST', 
                    url: 'stock-in.php',
                    data:{
                        stock_up: updateStock
                         <?php 
                        echo ', id: '.$row->pid.' '
                        ?>
                        <?php 
                        echo ', oldstock: '.$row->pstock.' '
                        ?>
                    },
                    success: function(data){swal(`Updated: ${updateStock}`);},
                    error: function(data){swal(`Error updating: ${updateStock}`);}
                });
            }

            });

        });
    });
```

The major issue I had was I didn't make the SQL query global at the top of my page and then applied `'.$row->pid.'`